# Failed to deploy artifact on Artifactory using Gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory, build.gradle

I want to deploy my java library artifact on Artifactory But I am getting the following error.
**Failed to deploy file: HTTP response code: 401. HTTP response message: Unauthorized.**

I followed the guide [gradle artifactory plugin](http://buransky.com/scala/publish-jar-artifact-using-gradle-to-artifactory/)

Below is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: "com.squareup.retrofit", name: "retrofit", version: "1.7.0"
    compile group: "com.squareup.okhttp", name: "okhttp", version: "2.0.0"
    compile group: "com.squareup.okhttp", name: "okhttp-urlconnection", version: "2.0.0"

}
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

group = 'com.xyz'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
            name = "maven-main-cache"
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '3.0.1')
    }
}
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
repositories {
    add buildscript.repositories.getByName("maven-main-cache")
}
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }

}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you have the opportunity to check logs on artifactory, since that will give you a better idea why it's failing

Comment: Hmm, you're trying to publish a snaphsot artifact ("x.y.z-SNAPSHOT") into a release repository. By default, artifactory does not allow this. I guess logs on artifactory will tell you the same.

Comment: or you are allowed to publish it but don't have (delete) permissions to overwrite a previous deploy. And I guess there are other explanations as well...

Comment: No I am not trying to publish snapshot artifact into release repository. you can see in publish closure repoKey=libs-snapshot-local. I do have permission for deploy.

Comment: I am admin and I have all permissions.

Comment: 20141126140940|16|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin |PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/infibeam/DAM_Consumer/1.0.0/DAM_Consumer-1.0.0.pom;build.name=DAM_Consumer;build.timestamp=1416991178596;build.number=1416991179079|HTTP/1.1|401|1012
 this is the request log i got from Artifactory logs.

Comment: indeed, I was wrong about snapshot artifact & release repo. The artifactory logs aren't helping, are you sure it is about *your* deploy (groupid/version does not conform) ? Maybe posting your gradle output will help (with '-i' of or '-d').

Comment: Please look at JFrog gradle project example in github
https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle2-example

Answer (score 0):

It can be happened when  ~/.m2/settings.xml or $GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties are corrupted. Explicitly when you use encrypted password for Artifactory access. Try to regenerated it again.